# How to update a UILabel without refreshing the main view?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to use the collection view delegate to update a UILabel on the main view. However, once the label updates, it updates the whole view which means it goes back to the start of the screen - before an animation. Is it possible to only update the monthLabel and not everything?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell2 = CollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookingDateCollectionCellClass

    let later = getDate(indexPath.row + 5).day
    print(later)


    let date: String = String(later)
    print(date)
    cell2.dateLabel.text = date

    let day = getDateData(indexPath.row + 5).dayOfWeek()
    print(day)
    cell2.dayLabel.text = dayShortFromNumber(day!)


    self.monthlabel.text = monthFromNumber(getDate(indexPath.row + 5).month)

    return cell2

}
```

This is the screen before the start animation:
[image: App with CollectionView before animation]
This is the screen after the start animation:
[image: App with CollectionView after animation]

Comment: use reloadrowatindexpath as we do in UITableViewcell. read it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707679/ios-reload-single-cell-of-uicollectionview   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296929/uicollectionview-update-a-single-cell

Comment: The label is in a separate view from the collection view. @Gagan_iOS

Comment: in this case either  use protocol or use NSNotification for message communication & update task.