# Xcode reload just one cell in UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to reload just one cell in a `UICollectionView`.

I know in `UITableView` it is something like this :

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

but what about `UICollectionView`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView update a single cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296929/uicollectionview-update-a-single-cell)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the method called [reloadItemsAtIndexPaths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:):

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell]];
```

Answer (score 2):

For swift 4 use this code:-

```
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])
```