# UICollectionView reload only first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView in my app and i want to reload only first cell of collection view.
How can i reload only first cell of UICollectionView?

Comment: `[yourCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 section:0]];`?

Comment: It gives error: No known class method of selector 'indexPathForRow:section:'

Comment: Modified the code in my comment. First Cell: You mean first cell visible, or first cell (whatever it's visible or not)?

Comment: Whatever visible or not but first cell of collection view

Comment: The first cell should be at index path with 0 as section and 0 as row. Check my code.

Comment: Yes i already tried that, but as i told you it gives me error- No known class method of selector 'indexPathForRow:section:'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96537/discussion-between-divyesh-savaliya-and-larme).

Comment: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]`, as specified by the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection I misread the method declaration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView update a single cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296929/uicollectionview-update-a-single-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:), method of `UICollectionView` to reload the first cell.

The index path of first cell is row:0 section:0.
NSIndexPath provides a method to create one with a row and a section: [`indexPathForRow:inSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection).

So the way to reload the first cell is:

```
[youCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct but not indexpath for row . its a indexpath for item

Answer (score 0):

collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])