# How to refresh data only in supplementary view in collectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Right now my code is to refresh all the data in collectionview by  `collectionView?.reloadData()` but how can i only refresh the data in  supplementary view or header view not all the data?

Thanks

Comment: `reloadData()` only reloads visible cells or views, so it's really fast. Why do you want to reload just the header?

Comment: Because reloadData() reload all the pic cell and make it slower and i only want to reload the text in the header view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView update a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296929/uicollectionview-update-a-single-cell)